# How do I use JavaScript when the HTML body loads?

Tags: javascript, html, onload

I tried doing this on my website, but it's not working. Do I need some sort of a link?

```
<body onload=“alert(‘Today only - 10% off on a weekend - coupon code ZenTen’);”>
```

Comment: Use the correct quotation marks: `"` and `'`, not `“` or `‘`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have should work, the only problem I can see is that your quotes aren't the standard quotes. Try this code.

```
<body onload="alert('Today only - 10% off on a weekend - coupon code ZenTen');">
```

Answer (score -1):

[Edit]: Standard quotes are needed here:

`<body onload="alert('Today only - 10% off on a weekend - coupon code ZenTen');">`

However, if you have control over the html of the page, it's advisable to load a library like [jQuery](http://learn.jquery.com/) and call a jQuery function like:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    alert("Today only - 10% off on a weekend - coupon code ZenTen");
});
```

Comment: `javascript:` has no meaning in inline event handlers.